# Display sidebar only if it has content

Tags: widgets

I have registered a new sidebar. Here is my code in functions.php:

```
register_sidebar(array(
'name'=>'1',
'before_widget' => '<div class="div1">',
'after_widget' => '</div>',
'before_title' => '',
'after_title' => '',
));
```

How do I get to display this sidebar. I want to do something like this:

> if sidebar(1) doesn't have widgets, it should not be displayed
>
> if sidebar(1) have widgets to display, it must display

```
<div class="alllist">
 <div class="div1"></div> 
 <div class="div1"></div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `is_active_sidebar` to check if sidebar has any widgets or not. Display sidebar only if `is_active_sidebar` returns true.

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-name' ) ) : ?>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-name' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! i'm found in `http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_active_sidebar`